# Disable focus on Pivot

Tags: c++, uwp

I want to disable tab navigation on a `Pivot` control as my control is already handling tabs. I have tried many approaches such as setting `IsTabStop=false` and removing focus on `GotFocus` event like this

```
mPivot->GotFocus += ref new RoutedEventHandler([](Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e) { mPivot->Focus(Windows::UI::Xaml::FocusState::Unfocused); });
```

But this results in crash with *The parameter is incorrect*. What should be the official way to do this? Also, how to achieve similar thing for a `ListView`?

EDIT: I found a hackish way to fix the crash: Instead of forcing `Unfocused` on the `Pivot`, I should artificially put focus on my control.

```
mPivot->GotFocus += ref new RoutedEventHandler([](Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    mControl->Focus(Windows::UI::Xaml::FocusState::Programmatic);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the underline below the pivot item header on focus?

Comment: @JustinXL Not just that. What I want is that when I pressed Tab key, the system should not (remove focus from my custom control which already handles Tab on `KeyDown` and) focus on the `Pivot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completely disable *tab navigation* on a `Pivot`, you will need to disable one special element called `HeaderClipper` inside `Pivot` style.

Go grab the default `Pivot` style [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), locate the `HeaderClipper` element and set `IsTabStop="False"` on it.

Note if there are controls inside your `Pivot` that are set to receive focus(i.e. `IsTabStop="True"`), they will still do. If you don't want this behavior, simply disable them by setting `IsTabStop` to `False`.